# Sorting a file in-place with Shell sort

Tags: c++, in-place

I have been asked to sort a file in-place using shell sort (and quick sort too, but I think that if I find the way to do one I will be able to do both of them). I have been thinking what could be helpful but I can't find a way to do it. I have the algorithm for an array, but I can't think a way to get it to work with a file.

Is there any way this can be done?

Edit:

With the help of the code posted by André Puel I was able to write some code that is working for the moment, here it is if you want to check it out:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <fstream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <sstream>
using namespace std;

int toNum(const string &s) {
  stringstream ss(s);
  int n;
  ss >> n;
  return n;
}

string toStr(int n) {
  stringstream ss;
  ss << n;
  string s;
  ss >> s;
  return string(5 - s.size(),' ') + s;
}

int getNum(fstream &f,int pos) {
  f.seekg(pos*5);
  string s;
  for(int i = 0; i < 5; ++i) s += f.get();
  return toNum(s);
}

void putNum(fstream &f, int pos,int n) {
  f.seekp(pos*5);
  f.write(toStr(n).c_str(),5);
}

int main() {
  fstream input("entrada1",fstream::in | fstream::out);
  string aux;
  getline(input,aux);
  int n = aux.size() / 5,temp,j;

  int gaps[] = {701,301,132,57,23,10,4,1};
  int g = sizeof(gaps)/sizeof(gaps[0]);
  for(int k = 0; k < g; ++k) {
    for(int i = k; i < n; ++i) {
      temp = getNum(input,i);
      for(j = i; j >= k and getNum(input,j - k) > temp; j -= k) {
        putNum(input,j,getNum(input,j - k));
      }
      putNum(input,j,temp);
    }
  }
  input.close();
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: When you say in place, are you saying they want you to read in the contents of a file, perform some sorting operation, and rewrite the original file back out sorted?

Comment: Are you already aware of the methods "tellp","seekp","tellg" and "seekg"?

Comment: at a very simple level, you can use a file pointer and seek as you would an array index, meaning no difference in algorithm really

Comment: @RobGoodwin Unlikely. The basic idea of external sorting is that you *don't* have to read all contents into memory first.

Comment: Oh, okay. Well in that case - read the file into an array, sort it and write it back?

Comment: @us2012 Sorry, I was not that clear, I was not suggesting that you read in everything before sorting, just that the file is read in and sorted ( either as it is read in or otherwise), and then the original file is basically rewritten is all I was asking.

Comment: i think that usually when people say in place file sorting, it's meant that the file is HUGE and doesn't fit in memory. that's my best guess... so some method that operates with good locality is ideal.

Comment: I can use other files to perform the operations, but I can't use any data structures (arrays, lists, graphs, ...)

Comment: I just read about the tellp seekp methods, but they wouldn't be very helpful since the input can have 1,2,3 or even 4 digits and I wouldn't know where to place the next number.

Comment: @hinafu are you dealing with text files or binary files? Text files are way more complicated to deal (for your problem) than binary files.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you open a file in C++ you have two pointers. The getter pointer and the putter pointer. They indicate where in the file you are writing and reading.

Using [seekp](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ostream/ostream/seekp/), you may tell where you wanna write. Using [tellp](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ostream/ostream/tellp/) you know where you are going to write. Everytime you write something the putter pointer advances automatically.

The same goes to the getter pointer, the functions are [seekg](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/seekg/) and [tellg](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/tellg/).

Using theses operations you may easily simulate an array. Let me show you some code:

```
class FileArray {
public:
    FileArray(const char* path) 
    : file(path, std::fstream::app|std::fstream::binary)
    {
        file.seekg(0,std::fstream::end);
        size = file.tellg();
    }

    void write(unsigned pos, char data) {
        assert(pos < size );
        file.tellp(pos);
        file.put(data);
    }

    char read(unsigned pos) {
        assert(pos < size);
        file.seekg(pos);
        return file.get();
    }
private:
    std::fstream file;
    std::size_t size;
}
```

This is a naive way to deal with a file because you are supposing random access. Well, random access is true, but it may be slow. File streams works faster when you access data that are near each other (spacial locality).

Even though, it is a nice way to start dealing with your problem, you with get experienced with file IO and you will end figuring out ways to improve the performance for your specific problem. Lets keep the baby steps.

Other thing that I want you to note is that when you perform a write, the data is redirected to the fstream that will write to the file. I know that the kernel will try to cache this stuff, and optimize the speed, but still would be better if you had some kind of cache layer to avoid writing directly to the disk.

Finally, I supposed that you are dealing with chars (because it would be easier), but you can deal with other data types, you will just need to be careful about the indexing and the size of the data type. For example, `long long` type does have size of 8 bytes, if you want to access the first element in your *file-array* you will access the position 8*0, and you will have to read 8 bytes. If you want the 10th element, you will access the position 8*10 and again read 8 bytes of data to construct the `long long` value.